# Still Another update is currently in progress by updating WordPress 5.3

Tags: updates

I tried to find with this select statement.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE 'option_name' LIKE '%core_update%'
```

Zero lines result.

What can I do beside update by hand. I only want to use the update button instead.

Thanks in advance.
Hans

Answer (score 1):

Something went wrong while you were updating your website.

Two solutions :

1/ Install and activate this plugin : [Fix Another Update In Progress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fix-another-update-in-progress/). In your settings, simply click on "Fix Another Update In Progress" and the plugin is going to fix your problem in a few seconds.

(Before using following solution, backup of your website.)
2/ Manually : In order to fix the problem manually, you can simply locate (using you ftp client) your **upgrade** folder and delete it. The upgrade folder is located under the wp-content folder (dont suppress this one !).

If the problem is persisting, try to locate (using your ftp client) a .maintenance file at the root of your server and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress there are two update locks:

- core_updater
- auto_updater

So, you can fix this issue by deleting the update locks.

Use below code to delete the lock's:

```
delete_option( 'core_updater.lock' );
delete_option( 'auto_updater.lock' );
```

You can delete the update locks with CLI command too. Checkout how to [delete them with CLI](https://wp.me/p4Ams0-15y) command.

Use the WordPress plugin
[fix-update-in-process](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fix-update-in-process/) which show the existing locks and fix the issue with one click.